# git credentials and folder permissions when executing within a program

Tags: c#, git, ubuntu, sudo

I've written a program that clones and pulls lots of git repos (to try to estimate time spent on projects) and also serves as a website to present data. The program is written in C# on using Visual Studio for Mac and runs fine locally, but I'm having trouble when deployed onto an Ubuntu 16.0.4 machine.

The program runs as the `www-data` user. It needs to be able to do two things:

- Create directories
- Do `git clone` and `git pull` on those directories over HTTP.

My problem is to do with permissions. When the new directories are created, they are owned by the `www-data` user. I've set up a global credential store to put the necessary git credentials to access the repos, but that's created under my `ubuntu` user.

I've tried fiddling with the `visudo` stuff so that the `www-data` user can execute the `git` commands as the `ubuntu` user, like the last [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44711929/3791156), but that still leaves me with a folder permissions problem.

I've read a bunch of similar questions on this, and they all seem to include a step where you manually change the folder permissions where you're storing the repository. However, in my case the folders get created on the fly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just sudo to the www-data user and setup git credentials the normal way for that user?

Comment: Thanks for the comment - that is precisely what I tried to do at the beginning (that is my preferred scenario). However, for some reason the git commands to set the credential store and save those credentials won't work. I suspect it's because the home directory of the www-data user is `/var/www` for which the www-data users doesn't have write access. This is a weird tricky problem.